# C++ function that calculates wage of employees

Tags: c++

So I was making a function that calculates the wage of an employee and outputs the wage and how many hours overtime they worked.

the output looks like this:

```
Enter hours worked (-1 to end): 41
Enter hourly rate of the worker ($00.00): 10.00
Employee worked 1 hour(s) overtime for a value of $15.00
Salary is $415.00
```

the only problem I had was that the function ended after the output above.
how do I keep asking the user for hours worked until a -1 is entered?
This is what I have:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double salary;
    int hours;
    int overtime;
    double rate;
    int work_limit = 40;
    double overtimePay;

    std::cout << "Enter hours worked (-1 to end): ";
    std::cin >> hours;

    if(hours < 0);
    std::cout << "Enter hourly rate of worker ($00.00): ";
    std::cin >> rate;

    overtime = hours - work_limit;
    overtimePay = (overtime * rate) + (0.5 * rate * overtime);

    if(hours > work_limit)
        std::cout << "Employee worked " << overtime << " hour(s overtime for a value of $" << overtimePay << std::endl;

    salary = hours * rate;

    salary = (work_limit *  rate) + (overtime * rate * 1.5);
    std::cout << "Salary is: $" << salary << "\n\n";
}
```

Comment: use a `while` or `do-while` loop

Comment: `overtime = hours - work_limit;`  You should check first before calculating this. I mean what happens if hours is less than work_limit? Edit:  Maybe move the calculation down to after the check and make a block in that if. I mean `if(hours > work_limit) { calculate and print overtime}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply wrap the core part in a `while` loop:

```
// loop infinitely
// exit from loop happens via if check right below
while(true){
    std::cout << "Enter hours worked (-1 to end): ";
    std::cin >> hours;

    // check wether the user wants to end
    // and if so, break out of the loop
    if (hours == -1) {
        break;
    }

    std::cout << "Enter hourly rate of worker ($00.00): ";
    std::cin >> rate;

    overtime = hours - work_limit;
    overtimePay = (overtime * rate) + (0.5 * rate * overtime);

    if(hours > work_limit)
        std::cout << "Employee worked " << overtime << " hour(s overtime for a value of $" << overtimePay << std::endl;

    salary = hours * rate;

    salary = (work_limit *  rate) + (overtime * rate * 1.5);
    std::cout << "Salary is: $" << salary << "\n\n";
}
```

Comment: i fixed the missing `;`, but you better also remove `if(hours < 0);` and adding a little explanation would also help ;)